# Customize resource choice to transport the pallets with a specific forklift

Tags: anylogic

I would like to store pallets with the forklift where id=1. I create a database with the different IDs and connect it with my forklift population. After that I create a custom resource choice condition where the forklift with id=1 should store the pallets. It doesn't work, the process stuck and the forklift doesn't move.

[database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ygcMi.png)

[agentpopulation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BA3DD.png)

[resourcepool](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w42bk.png)

[rackstore_resourcechoicecondition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IjfJq.png)

Answer (score 0):

this is the typical error in which you created a population of Forklifts and then you think they will magically become part of your resourcepool... but they don't... they are just forklifts that will not even show in your simulation and will do nothing... the forklifts that are shown in your simulation are the ones generated throught the resourcepool NOT using the database... using custom population doesn't mean that the resourcepool will use the population you created with your database.

**SOLUTION**

To do what you want to do, first be SURE to erase that population you just created... forklifts will be nothing but a resource type

Second be sure that your database doesn't have the same name than your forklift agent type or population.

Then in your resourcepool capacity use:

```
(int) selectFrom(forklifts_db).count()
```

note that im using forklifts_db as your database to be sure you are using a different name

Then on new unit, use this

```
((Forklift)unit).id=(int) selectFrom(forklifts_db)
    .where(forklifts_db.id.goe(self.size()))
    .firstResult(forklifts_db.id);
```

Comment: Thank you very much! Can I read about this somewhere? I'm a complete anylogic and java beginner.. would be nice when you could recommend me something where I could learn something about this

Comment: about this specifically, there's nothing... I talk about it a little bit on my course but not a lot

Comment: Is it the same method when I would like to give my pallets ids to create different types?

Comment: no... different method, you should use the same population you created with your technique and then use an enter block to put those agents you created from the database into your flow.

Comment: Could I also use a source block?

Comment: I don't see how you could use a source... unless you add an arrival date to your database, but anyways, you have too many questions and this one is answered